# VBA Save As Current Filename +01

Tags: vba, excel, iteration, filenames, save-as

I'm looking to write a macro to save my current version filename +1 instance of the version. For each new day the version would reset to `v01`. Ex. Current = DailySheet_20150221v01; Save As = DailySheet_20150221v02; Next Day = DailySheet_20150222v01

While increasing the version number, I am hoping the version won't have to contain the `v0` once `v10`+ has been reached.

I was able to workout how to save the file with today's date:

```
Sub CopyDailySheet()

Dim datestr As String

datestr = Format(Now, "yyyymmdd")

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "D:\Projects\Daily Sheet\DailySheet_" & datestr & ".xlsx"

End Sub
```

but need additional help in finding the version addition. Could I set the    `SaveAs` to a string, then run it through a For/If - Then set?

Comment: Is the date independent of the version number, or do you reset the version number to "1" every day?

Comment: @Porcupine911 Yes, I do reset the version number to "1" every day

Comment: Then we'll have to go with something like Bu_ali's powershell answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this out to a couple of my friends and below is their solution:

```
Sub Copy_DailySheet()

Dim datestr As String, f As String, CurrentFileDate As String, _
    CurrentVersion As String, SaveAsDate As String, SaveAsVersion As String


    f = ThisWorkbook.FullName
    SaveAsDate = Format(Now, "yyyymmdd")
    ary = Split(f, "_")
    bry = Split(ary(UBound(ary)), "v")
    cry = Split(bry(UBound(bry)), ".")
    CurrentFileDate = bry(0)
    CurrentVersion = cry(0)
    SaveAsDate = Format(Now, "yyyymmdd")

    If SaveAsDate = CurrentFileDate Then
        SaveAsVersion = CurrentVersion + 1
    Else
        SaveAsVersion = 1
    End If

    If SaveAsVersion < 10 Then
        ThisWorkbook.SaveAs "D:\Projects\Daily Sheet\DailySheet_" & SaveAsDate & "v0" & SaveAsVersion & ".xlsm"
    Else
        ThisWorkbook.SaveAs "D:\Projects\Daily Sheet\Daily Sheet_" & SaveAsDate & "v" & SaveAsVersion & ".xlsm"
    End If

End Sub
```

Thanks to all those who contributed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
Sub CopyDailySheet()

'Variables declaration
Dim path As String
Dim sht_nm As String
Dim datestr As String
Dim rev As Integer
Dim chk_fil As Boolean
Dim ws As Object

'Variables initialization
path = "D:\Projects\Daily_Sheet"
sht_nm = "DailySheet"
datestr = Format(Now, "yyyymmdd")
rev = 0

'Create new Windows Shell object
Set ws = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

'Check the latest existing revision number
Do
rev = rev + 1
chk_fil = ws.Exec("powershell test-path " & path & "\" & sht_nm & "_" & datestr & "v" & Format(rev, "00") & ".*").StdOut.ReadLine
Loop While chk_fil = True

'Save File with new revision number
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs path & "\" & sht_nm & "_" & datestr & "v" & Format(rev, "00") & ".xlsm"

End Sub
```

Comment: Is there anything special I need to do for the `WshShell`? I am getting a _Compile Error: User-defined type not defined_ on the `Dim ws As WshShell`.

Comment: Oh sorry, forgot to mention that you should include the corresponding reference. You can do this as following:
1- Open MS VBA in Excel
2- Click on **Tools** in the toolbar
3- Choose **References**
4- Look for **Windows Script Host Object Model** reference and add it by checking the box right next to it
5- Click **OK**
6- Compile the script again

Comment: Or you can just replace the following:
`Dim ws As WshShell` with `Dim ws As Object`
And
`Set ws = New WshShell` with `Set ws = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")`

Comment: This will open and run Windows PowerShell, but then delivers a _Run-Time error '13': Type mismatch_ . Debugging highlights `chk_fil = ws.Exec("powershell test-path " & path & "\" & sht_nm & "_" & datestr & "v" & Format(rev, "00") & ".*").StdOut.ReadLine`

Comment: You just need to change the path name. Anyway, I've changed it for you in the code to **"D:\Projects\Daily Sheet"**, and changed the declaration of the **ws** variable (to be late-bound) so you don't face that compiling error anymore. Please copy the code again.

Comment: I attempted this with the updated information, but it returns the same results. For security purposes, the file doesn't actually save to **"D:\"** but rather to my desktop; would this be what is causing the error?

Comment: Yes, you're right. That's happening because of the space in the folder name "Daily Sheet". So, I've just changed it to be "Daily_Sheet" instead. But remember, **you need to rename the folder** as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the current filename I would use something like:

```
Public Function GetNewFileName(s As String) As String
    ary = Split(s, "v")
    n = "0" & CStr(CLng(ary(1)) + 1)
    GetNewFileName = ary(0) & "v" & ary(1)
End Function
```

Tested with:

```
Sub MAIN()
    strng = GetNewFileName("DailySheet_20150221v02")
    MsgBox strng
End Sub
```

Comment: So that always pads with a zero. "v010"?

Comment: @Gary's Student I would love to understand your Function and Sub, but am not understanding how the information passes through. When I run this, I get the `MsgBox` with `DailySheet_20150221v02`. Am I right to place these within the same module?